# Is there any neat selector for other than this with this class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, jquery-selectors

Example:

```
<div>
    <A><span class="bla">test</span></a>
    <A><span class="bla">test test</span></a>
    <A><span class="bla">test test test</span></a>
</div>
```

Just wondering if we could do something like this:

```
$('span.bla').click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('selected').others_with_this_class().removeClass('selected');
});
```

Or would we really need to make two different selectors, and process them one by one.

**EDIT**:

Thanks everyone with ideas, I found up doing something like this: :-)

```
if (!$(this).hasClass('selected'))
$(this).addClass('selected').parent().siblings('a').children('.selected').removeClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$('span.bla').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected')
           .parent()
           .siblings()
           .children('span')
           .removeClass('selected');
});
```

This will find the parent of the span (`<a>`), all it's siblings, and any `<span>`s that are children of those siblings, and add `.current` to them.

Comment: Edited. You should have been able to work out how to fix it anyway; it's trivial with jQuery.

Comment: well this looks better, but this will choose a.selected, not span.selcted, so I guess would be better something like... .siblings('a').children('span.selected')

Comment: No, this will only add/remove `.selected` to/from `<span>`s. I'm using `$.parent()`, then going back down a level to a `<span>` using `$.children()`.

Comment: yes, but becasue you went go the parent level, you will select siblings of a with .selected class

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean "process them one by one"?

Why not just remove the class from the `.selected` items, and then add the class to your clicked item:

```
$('span.bla').click(function(){
   $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to clear the class from everything, then add it to the single class:

```
$('span.bla').click( function() {
    $('span.bla').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('span.bla').click(function(){
   $('span.bla').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```